# How to disable non-standard features in SML/NJ

Tags: sml, smlnj

SML/NJ provides a series of [non-standard features](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/features.html), such as higher-order modules, vector literal syntax, etc.

Is there a way to disable these non-standard features in SML/NJ, through some command-line param maybe, or, ideally, using a CM directive?

Comment: Plus one, but I'm pretty sure the answer is "no". :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just by looking at the grammar used by the parser, I'm going to say that there is not a way to do this. From "admin/base/compiler/Parse/parse/ml.grm":

```
apat'   : OP ident      (VarPat [varSymbol ident])
| ID DOT qid        (VarPat (strSymbol ID :: qid varSymbol))
| int           (IntPat int)
| WORD          (WordPat WORD)
| STRING        (StringPat STRING)
| CHAR          (CharPat CHAR)
| WILD          (WildPat)
| LBRACKET RBRACKET (ListPat nil)
| LBRACKET pat_list RBRACKET    (ListPat pat_list)
| VECTORSTART RBRACKET  (VectorPat nil)
| VECTORSTART pat_list RBRACKET (VectorPat pat_list)
| LBRACE RBRACE     (unitPat)
| LBRACE plabels RBRACE (let val (d,f) = plabels
                         in RecordPat{def=d,flexibility=f}
                         end)
```

The `VectorPat` stuff is fully mixed in with the rest of the patterns.  A recursive grep for `VectorPat` also will show that there aren't any options to turn this off anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen that as well, at which point I stopped looking any further. It's a pity it can't be done :(

Comment: May I ask why you want to disable these features?  Perhaps there is a workaround of some sort.  If you run your program through MLton, giving it the `-stop tc` flag, it will type check the program, but nothing further.  This could verify the absence of some SML/NJ extensions

Comment: I just wanted to remain as compatible as possible with all the compilers that exist without having to use more than one during development. SML/NJ is nice during development, because it offers a very quick feedback loop. I have thought of using MLton just for this purpose, but it's pretty slow due to it being an optimizing compiler. However, I haven't tried the `-stop tc` option, because I didn't know about it. I'll give it a try. Thanks!